# mui datagrid when I switch to the second page, the line numbering starts anew

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Mui datagrid when I switch to the second page, the line numbering starts anew.
This comes when using paginationMode="server"
Mui version v5

```
     <DataGrid
      getRowId={(row) => row.id}
      rows={rows.data}
      columns={Column(t)}
      pageSize={filter.per_page}
      onPageSizeChange={(per_page) => {
        filter.changePerPage(per_page);
      }}
      loading={loading}
      page={rows.page - 1}
      rowCount={rows.total}
      autoHeight
      disableSelectionOnClick
      disableColumnSelector={true}
      hideFooterSelectedRowCount
      paginationMode="server"
      onPageChange={(page) => {
        filter.toPage(page + 1);
      }}
    />
```

[
{
field: '№',
headerName: '№',
width: 50,
sortable: true,
renderCell: (index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1,
},
{
field: 'name',
headerName: 'name',
width: 500,
},
{
field: 'title',
headerName: 'title',
width: 400,
},
]

for example, the numbering of table rows 1, 2, 3, 4, when you turn the page 5, 6, 7, 8 should be continued. Should not begin again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.